# How long should I cure or brine Turkey Pastrami?

Tags: turkey, brining, curing

I want to make turkey pastrami for the first time. I have made beef pastrami successfully a few times. All the recipes for turkey pastrami call for curing or brining the turkey for a very short amount of time (1-3 days) compared to all the beef pastrami recipes (7+ days). The turkey, especially the breast, isn't any thinner than the beef. Is there something about turkey that makes it cure faster?

How long does the turkey need to cure for a successful pastrami?